# Linq join between IQueryable and List<int> is taking too long to be executed

Tags: c#, linq

I have this simple join query which is taking too long to execute.

```
filteredTags = (from ft in filteredTags
                join at in activeTagIds on ft.ID equals at
                select ft).ToArray();
```

Here filteredTags is the Iqueryable and activeTagIds is the List.

When I tried to see the built query it is doing an UNION ALL to all the ids in activeTagIds, which is what making my query execution slow.

```
....
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    5620 AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    5621 AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]
.... so on..
```

How do I avoid this extra long query and make it simpler for faster execution time?

Comment: where did the `IQueryable` come from?  if it's coming from the database, and hasn't been pulled server-side (by calling `.ToList()` on it, e.g.), it could be going to a database with every iteration. over the queryable.

Comment: Try a `where activeTagIds.Contains(ft.ID)` instead

Comment: @juharr it eems to lot faster now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check whether filtered tag id is in active tag ids:

```
filteredTags = filteredTags.Where(ft => activeTagIds.Contains(ft.ID)).ToArray()
```

Or if you prefer mix of query and method syntax:

```
filteredTags = (from ft in filteredTags
                where activeTagIds.Contains(ft.ID)
                select ft).ToArray();
```

Both will generate `IN` SQL query.